# Is there any issues after upgrading to Gnome 16.10 with Intel Graphic Cards?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, 16.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, but I'm having some problems with my graphics card:

**The display twinkles and flickers!**

I prefer to work only with my Intel Haswell Graphics Card. BUT it seems the Intel Graphics Card are not compatible with the Gnome 16.10. Or?

My PC-Details:

*Acer Aspire V3-772G / i7-4702 2.2Ghz / Nvidia GeForce 750M*
 / 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux (4.8.0-22-generic)

Current status of Graphic card:

*00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])*

*Kernel driver in use: i915*

*Kernel modules: i915*

Additional Drivers:

*Set on Using X.Org.X Server - Nouveau display driver AND Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcide*

NVIDIA X Server Settings:

*GPU set on Intel (Power Saving Mode)*

What I've tried to do:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
$ sudo apt-get purge xorg-* xserver-xorg; sudo apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg; sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg
$ sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-desktop-environment; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

AND

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

AND following the steps of this site:

http://technozed.com/fix-nvidia-graphical-issues-installing-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: which gnome version ? `gnome-shell --version`

Comment: @SeverusTux - GNOME Shell 3.20.4

Comment: Do you know how AskUbuntu's Search function (top right) works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to prevent display flickering under the i915 driver, there are several kernel parameters to use, but in my own case--running Gnome Ubuntu 16.10 with an Intel Haswell Mobile display (i915) and no secondary GPUs--I used the following and have had no flickering problems:

```
i915.enable_psr=0
```

So, in grub, you might see something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0”
```

For details on one such conversation about i915-related display flicker under Ubuntu, see this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339302