# 16.10 upgrade breaks graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, upgrade, graphics, 16.10

I have an Acer Aspire V3-772 laptop set up to dual boot into Windows 10 and Ubuntu. It has NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760M and Intel HD Graphics 4600. It has been running fine on Ubuntu 16.04. I just upgraded to 16.10 and now the video makes it just about unusable. The screen either goes to black after 2 seconds and stays black until you move the mouse (as soon as you stop moving the mouse, the screen goes black again) or it fills with white noise that persists for about 20 seconds and then returns to a rapidly flickering desktop. The only way to make it usable is to boot from the 4.4 kernel rather than the new 4.8. Does anyone have any advice as to how to make the graphics usable on the 4.8 kernel?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/837283/is-there-any-issues-after-upgrading-to-gnome-16-10-with-intel-graphic-cards?rq=1