# Can no longer use any flavors of Ubuntu as screen randomly flashes black

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 16.10, screen, xserver

So since Ubuntu 16.10 was released (and its X server was backported to 16.04.2) I can no longer use any version of Ubuntu. Whether it's Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome or Kubuntu, none of them are usable as the screen randomly flashes black, mainly while typing. This problem does not occur on Linux Mint (even the 18.2) or on Antergos. But I'd prefer using Ubuntu.

Now when 16.04.2 came out, I solved the issue by doing these steps:

First I'd remove the new X stack

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
```

Then I'd reinstall the old one

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core

sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Unfortunately from 16.10 onwards those commands no longer work. So I can no longer use them.

How can fix this?

I'm currently using Windows because of this issue and I have absolutely no issue with it.

My computer is a laptop, the EliteBook 8440p. The processor is an Intel Core i5 M520 2.4 GHz, I have 4 GB of RAM and the graphic card is just listed as Intel(R) HD Graphics Ironlake Intel Auburndale/Arrandale Processor - Integrated Graphics Controller [Hewlett-Packard] with 1.68GB on RAM.

Thanks!

Comment: What arguments speak against staying with 16.04's GA stack?

Comment: Is your problem related to [https://askubuntu.com/questions/837283/is-there-any-issues-after-upgrading-to-gnome-16-10-with-intel-graphic-cards?rq=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837283/is-there-any-issues-after-upgrading-to-gnome-16-10-with-intel-graphic-cards?rq=1)

Comment: @ByteCommander: I would but I can't install it. The packages have the same name now but they're not the same version.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: It seems to be the same issue but I believe I did try this fix a while back to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I just tested again with a fresh Install and unfortunately it didn't work... :/